# Сколько запятых должно быть в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

**При выборе времени суток(1) ночь уже не кажется столь однозначным ответом(2) и(3) к предпочтительному званию(4) утро подбирается все ближе.**

Подскажите, на месте каких цифр должна стоять запятая?

Comment: Странное у Вас предложение. Можете дать контекст? Вдруг будет понятнее.

Comment: Этому предложению правильная постановка знаков не поможет. Выглядит оно как дословный перевод. Мысль в целом понятна, но форма совершенно неприемлема. К примеру, что мы выбираем, время суток или название для этого времени. И т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение в отрыве от контекста кажется странным. Попробую объяснить пунктуацию в зависимости от того, как мне представляется смысл.
Это сложносочиненное предложение с союзом "и".
***При выборе времени суток*** (когда?) — это обстоятельство времени, общий член для двух простых предложений, внутри которых запятые не требуются (нет ни уточняющих, ни сравнительных, ни причастных, ни деепричастных оборотов).

Правило: запятая перед "и" не ставится, если обе части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общий второстепенный член.
***Вскоре после восхода*** набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (Пушкин).

Думаю, что в Вашем предложении запятые не нужны.
**При выборе времени суток ночь уже не кажется столь однозначным ответом и к предпочтительному званию утро подбирается все ближе.**

[Трудные случаи пунктуации. Запятая перед союзом «И»](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)